# Adding a string value in datapoint of line series of Oxyplot

Tags: c#, oxyplot

Can anyone please tell how to add a string value in data point of line series in Oxyplot?

I have a list which is a key-value pair of string, double and wanted to add it to a data point.

Example:
string values are 10-15,15-20, ...

double values are 10, 20, 30, ...

I want my x-axis tick points to be displayed as for example (10-15, 15-20 and so on)

Following is the code:

```
foreach (var points in list)
{
   lineseriesobject.Points.Add(new OxyPlot.DataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(points.Key), Convert.ToDouble(points.Value)));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `PointAnnotation`!

```
foreach (var points in list)
{
  var pointAnnotation = new PointAnnotation()
  {
    X = Convert.ToDouble(points.Key),
    Y = Convert.ToDouble(points.Value),
    Text = String.Format("{0}-{1}",points.Key,points.Value)
  });
  lineSeriesObject.Points.Add(new OxyPlot.DataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(points.Key), Convert.ToDouble(points.Value)));
  plotModelObject.Annotations.Add(pointAnnotation);
}
plotModelObject.Series.Add(lineSeriesObject);
```

Just look at the [OxyPlot Example Browser](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/tree/develop/Source) under **Annotations**.